# LWC: Removing a class name on scroll

Tags: class, lightning-web-components, remove

I am trying to remove a class name once the user has scrolled a certain amount.

In my JS file for a LWC I have the following:

```
import { LightningElement, wire, api, track } from 'lwc';

function removeClass() {
    document.getElementsByClassName('outter-wrapper')[0].remove('outter-wrapper');
}

export default class SomeClass extends LightningElement {

    // some other code

    connectedCallback() {
        window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
            if (window.pageYOffset > 260) {
                removeClass();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get an error in the console saying `Cannot read property 'remove' of undefined`.

When I do execute `document.getElementsByClassName('outter-wrapper')[0].remove('outter-wrapper');` in the console it works no problem.

If this is the JS file for the LWC which contains a `div` with a class name `outter-wrapper` how come it cannot find it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, `document.` is not allowed in LWC because of locker-service. You should be using `this.template.` to identify the elements in HTML.

Instead, you can add something like this:

```
import { LightningElement, wire, api, track } from 'lwc';

export default class SomeClass extends LightningElement {

    // some other code

    connectedCallback() {
        window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
            if (window.pageYOffset > 260) {
                this.removeClass();
            }
        });
    }

    removeClass() {
        this.template.querySelectorAll('.outter-wrapper')[0].remove('outter-wrapper');
    }
}
```

**Note (based on comments):**

When you declare the function outside class, you are out of context of class and so `this` will be undefined and so you cannot access template. And `document` is exposed through secure object and so many methods on document will be unavailable. Still if you want to use functions outside class, you will need to pass the class reference via parameter like below:

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

function check(cls) {
    cls.template.querySelector('.myclass').remove('myclass');
}

export default class Poc extends LightningElement {
    remove() {
        check(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I see that you moved `removeClass()` inside my `SomeClass` class. I thought if the function is not to be referenced from the component then I should probably not put it inside the class. Is my trail of thought wrong?

Comment: adding in answer

Answer (score 1):

You should not be using `document` to access the element. instead use `this.template`

See important note in the bottom of the documentation:
[Docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/create_components_dom_work)